# Remove items from array in MongoDB

Tags: database, mongodb, mongodb-query

The database I have is a list of contacts with a structure like this

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5bb4fff62dba3129388423fa"),
        "user_id" : 1,
        "custom_list_id" : "VDFLVPMK",
        "list_name" : "New Test List",
        "contacts" : [
                {
                        "email" : "test1@gmail.com",
                        "first_name" : "Jane",
                        "last_name" : "Doe",
                        "address" : "",
                        "subscribed" : true,
                        "date_added" : ISODate("2018-10-03T17:44:30.975Z"),
                        "date_changed" : ISODate("2018-10-03T17:44:30.975Z")
                },
                {
                        "email" : "test@gmail.com",
                        "first_name" : "John",
                        "last_name" : "Doe",
                        "address" : "",
                        "subscribed" : true,
                        "date_added" : ISODate("2018-10-03T17:49:58.795Z"),
                        "date_changed" : ISODate("2018-10-03T17:49:58.795Z")
                }
        ]
}
```

I am trying to remove one person in the contacts without removing everything in the list. I am trying to run the command in the MongoDB terminal and it is not doing anything

**Command**

```
 db.customer__list__info.update({contacts:[]},{$pull:{'contacts.email':'test1@gmail.com'}})
```

**Result**

`WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 0, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 0 })`

What I would like is for it to get rid of everything inside the `{ }` with the specified email.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: `db.customer__list__info.update({ 'contacts.email': 'test1@gmail.com' }, { '$pull': {'contacts': { 'email': 'test1@gmail.com' }}})` ???

Comment: That worked! Thank you!